# Error in failure indication with unit test plugin(C/C++ Unit) used in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, cpputest

Error in Red bar display and failure indication in test cases, when used C/C++Unit(Cpputest plugin) with eclipse platform for unit testing.
I have downloaded the CppuTest package from the link;"https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest " and i have set it up in eclipse 4.16 for unit testing in eclipse platform using cygwin.

As i started integrating the unit test for our project, i noticed that only the test cases which were passing were listed under the test runs and neither is the red bar displayed indicating that some test cases have failed.

There are 18 test cases, but only 15 have been listed under the test run. Evidently neither are the failures indicated nor is the red bar displayed.

[image]

Comment: According to the screenshot, the execution of the tests has not yet been finished.

Comment: @howlger, the second screenshot is apparently to show there is failure when seen through console of the code coverage option which is built separately! but, in actual the execution is finished and the failures are not being listed out in C/C++Unit plugin which actually serves as a unit testing plugin in eclipse. I wish you could help in knowing why the error is not being reflected in the plugin and thereby no red indication in the failure bar.   Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Yes, the _Console_ view shows `<terminated>` and the stop button is disabled. But in the _C/C++ Unit_ view the stop buttons is still red. So it looks like the _C/C++ Unit_ view is waiting for something. Is there something in the Eclipse error log? Please make sure, this issue has been reported to the vendor of the Cpputest plugin.

Comment: @howlger, thanks for your response:), also i found this issue to be solved once i switched from cygwin to mingw toolchain, seems like cygwin is little buggy!